# Changing the position of the vertices in a plane

Tags: swift, scenekit

Is it possible to change the positions of the corners of an `SCNPlane`? Or do I have to make a custom plane to change the positions of its vertices?

EDIT:
So i have a SCNPlane or a custom created plane, and i want to atleast print the coordinates of the vertices that the plane has.

Answer (score 2):

For simple effects, you can effectively change the plane's corners by using the plane's transform matrix. You can do more complex effects with a shader modifier (see `SCNShadable`) or a morpher (see `SCNMorpher`). What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you use the transform matrix?

Comment: Edit your question and tell us precisely what you're trying to do with the vertices.

Comment: So i have a SCNPlane or a custom created plane, and i want to atleast print the coordinates of the vertices that the plane has.